# Object not found R

Tags: r, object

I've created a loop to iterate through a set of files and assign the data in the files to a variable

```
for(i in 1:8){
  infile <-paste("coauthor", i,".csv",sep="")
  coa[i]<-read.csv(infile,header = TRUE, sep="\t")
}
```

Yet I keep getting alternating errors

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  object 'infile' not found
```

and more frequently

```
Error in paste("coauthor", i, ".csv", sep = "") : object 'i' not found
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where are your files stored and what's the output of `getwd()`?

Comment: sorry, prior to executing this command I set the wd to the proper location like so `setwd("D:/n4jbatch")
getwd()` with getwd() producing the correct wd

Comment: You're getting two very different errors, i think more info is needed to figure this out.

Comment: Is this your original code of the for-loop?

Comment: yes it is. I think I may have an idea of what's going on. It appears that I had to highlight all the code to execute the script, which is  a pretty newb error. Now I am just getting the message Error in coa[i] <- read.csv(infile, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") : 
  object 'coa' not found

Comment: If you're using RStudio, please add the tag so others can find this question.

Comment: Have you created `coa` before running the loop, i.e., `coa <- list()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need for `for` loops. Second, if you do it this way, you need to pre-define `coa`. Third, you have to `setwd(...)` appropriately or `read.csv(...)` will not find the files.

```
setwd("<directory with coauther files...>")
# this just creates a bunch of files so we can read them back in...
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6, z=7:9)
lapply(1:5, function(i)write.csv(df,paste0("coauthor",i,".csv")))

# this is the code that reads them in. This is all you need.
coa <- lapply(1:5, function(i)read.csv(paste0("coauthor",i,".csv")))
```

Note that `coa` is now a list with 5 elements, each containing the contents of one of the files.

```
coa[1]
# [[1]]
#   X x y z
# 1 1 1 4 7
# 2 2 2 5 8
# 3 3 3 6 9
```

Comment: I changed pre-allocate to pre-define. The statement "no need for" implies that for loops are not necessary, which is absolutely correct.

Comment: In this particular instance I wanted to read the data from the files into the data frame, perform some modifications to the data frame, and then bind the modified frame to an existing data frame. Your answer on pre-define did help, and your solution may work for my broader problem, but I cannot tell.